# Executables commands not found in -bash terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, bash, npm, homebrew

Using a Mac Os X Yosemite was trying generate some scaffolding and this is what comes back in the bash terminal

-bash: some_command: not found

This happens with most of my commands like run, serve etc when trying to generate or use certain executable commands. General alias’s and commands like mv, ls, rm etc work fine

I’ve checked my $PATH and it seems correct:

$ /bin/echo $PATH
/Users/user_name/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/user_name/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

I checked to make certain npm, node, yomen,  grunt  etc show as installed with -v and shows updated and installed.

I’ve checked my ~.bash_profile appears and aliases but all seems fine.

The best I can gage is it has something to do possibly with npm and or Node and possibly Homebrew. So I’ve uninstalled, reinstalled and researched any similar like questions out there but nothing seems to work. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction here since I am at a lost. And I am not the best at the environment set up. So might not be looking at something thats staring at me in the face. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, whatever these mysterious commands you cannot execute are called (`run` and `serve`, perhaps?), where are they located along your PATH? A statement such as _I’ve checked my $PATH and it seems correct_ can only be reasonable if you've verified that these commands are in one of the directories specified in PATH.

Comment: Hi I am sorry ask this but how might I verify that. I certainly am not 100% clear on this part.

Comment: What command are you trying to run, and does it appear in any directory listed in `PATH`? For instance, if you are trying to run `foobar`, then does `/Users/user_name/.rbenv/shims/foobar` exist? Does `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/foobar` exist? etc.

Comment: Example I was trying to localhost docpad with docpad run or I try to create an Angular app with Yomen by typing Yo Angular. All show bash: command not found.

Comment: Are you sure you even installed yeoman, for example? `npm install -g yo`

Comment: Yes it comes up all is fine

Comment: Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version

Everything looks all right!

Comment: I highly suspect your CLI tools installed from npm are not being found in your `$PATH`. Do what I described in my answer and ensure that `$(npm config get prefix)/bin` is in your path.

Comment: is this what it should show since npm comes with node?-bash: /Users/aronfrenz/.node/bin: is a directory

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install whatever CLI tool you're trying to use first if you haven't already. For example:

```
npm install -g yo
```

That command installs yeoman into the global npm module directory. That directory should also be in your `$PATH`. To find the directory npm uses, type the following:

```
npm config get prefix
```

That will show you what directory npm is installing global modules to. In that directory there should be a `bin/` directory with symlinks for any CLI tools that came with a global module you installed. That `bin/` directory should be in your `$PATH` variable for bash to find command line scripts in there.

I'm using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage my node installations so when I run `npm config get prefix` my directory is: `/Users/chev/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0`. That's not the standard directory though. If you installed node with the default installer then yours will be different. When I do `echo $PATH` mine looks like this: `/Users/chev/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. Directories in path are separated by colons (`:`).

A common problem with node on OSX is the need to use `sudo` with npm commands because of permissions issues in the default global npm modules directory. If you're having issues like that I suggest you also start using something like [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). NVM allows you to install multiple node versions side by side, but even if you don't need that functionality it's still useful because it configures node & npm so that everything operates out of your home directory at `~/.nvm/` and avoids permission issues. No more `sudo`.

Comment: I believe it was installed thru Homewbrew and from what I read the sudo is highly reccommended against using, since it somehow conflicts with how it works. I now it worked for months until last week and somehow jsut stopped working

Comment: This is my path when I do echo $PATH /Users/aronfrenz/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/aronfrenz/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: So did you check your npm prefix or not? Telling me your `$PATH` tells me nothing if I don't know your npm prefix. I'm not sure if you misread my answer or what, but I am also telling you ***not*** to use `sudo` if you are.

Comment: $ npm config get prefix
/Users/aronfrenz/.node

Comment: Is the above what needs the bin added?

Comment: Exactly, so you should find `/Users/aronfrenz/.node/bin` in your `$PATH` and I don't see it in what you pasted above. That is almost certainly your issue. You can navigate to that directory manually and verify that there are symlinks in there for all the commands you tried to install. You can even run them from that directory to ensure they're working. `~/.node/bin/yo` should run the yeoman command even if bash can't find it when you just run `yo`. That will confirm they are installed and working. Now you just need to add `/Users/aronfrenz/.node/bin` to `$PATH` and you should be fixed up.

Comment: that's it! THANK YOU! And thanks to everyone else as well. This is my first time around with this type of issue and very appreciative of the help and guidance.

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to accept the answer :D